# C# Accessing properties of a parent class from derived classes

Tags: c#

I have a class named `PINPAD`, a base class named `Devices`, and two derived classes named `DevA` and `Dev B`

The issue is that the main class property `PINPAD.Status` needs to be updated from classes `DevA` and `DevB`

Here is the code:

```
public class CALLER()
{
  CALLER()
  {
    PINPAD PINPD = new PINPAD("A");
    //....
    MessageBox.Show(PINPD.Status);
  }
}

public class PINPAD()
{
    public Devices MyDev = null;
    public string Status = "";

    public PINPAD(string Model)
    {
        if (Model = "A")
        {
            DevA MyDev = new DevA()
        }
        else
        {
            DevB MyDev = new DevB()
        }

        MyDev.DoWork();
    }
}

public class Devices
{
    public virtual void DoWork() {}
}

public class DevA : Devices
{
    public override void DoWork() { }

    DevA()
    {
        PINPAD.Status = "Broken";
        //Status not avialable!
    }
}

public class DevB : Devices
{
    public override void DoWork() { }

    DevB()
    {
        PINPAD.Status = "Working!";
        //Status not avialable!
    }
}
```

Comment: You have not associated pinpad with anything by inheritance nor composition.

Comment: Could you update your question to include the error message you are getting?

Comment: does this even compile?

Comment: You can't put an assignment in an `if` statement like this: `if (Model = "A")`

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with parent/child relationships - `PINPAD` is a separate class. You either need to instantiate an instance of it to access the `Status` field, or make the field `static`. And you really should make that a property instead of a public field.

Comment: Also when you do this: `if (Model == "A") { DevA MyDev = new DevA(); }` you are creating a **new *local*** instance of `DevA` with the same name as the class field `MyDev` (and because you declare it inside the `if` block, it goes out of scope when the `if` block completes, so when you do `MyDev.DoWork();` you're not using the instance you just assigned). Instead, you probably want to do `MyDev = new DevA();` (remove the type declaration) so that the assignment is applied to the class field.

Comment: And you might consider renaming your class to `Device`. Normally a class name that's plural indicates that it's a collection type.

Comment: Hey Guys thanks for your comments
You are right not showing here the main call for the class PINPAD from another main program

PINPAD PINPD = new PINPAD("A");

where

MessageBrox.Show(PINPD.Status);

;

Answer (score 0):

You've declared `PINPAD.Status` as an instance field - meaning you have to have an object of the type `PINPAD` in order to access it.

```
var myPinpad = new PINPAD();
myPinpad.Status = "Whatever";
```

If you want there to just be one field that is available everywhere, declare the field `static`:

```
public static string Status = "";
```

Comment: this is the call from another program to this class

public class CALLER()
{
  CALLER()
  {

    PINPAD PINPD = new PINPAD("A");

    //....

    MessageBox.Show(PINPD.Status);

  }
}

Comment: this is the call from another program to this class

public class CALLER()
{
  CALLER()
  {
    PINPAD PINPD = new PINPAD("A");

    //....

    MessageBox.Show(PINPD.Status);

  }
}

Comment: Added the CALLER to the original question